# C++ - Get value of a particular memory address

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, dereference, memory-address

I was wondering whether it is possible to do something like this:

```
unsigned int address = 0x0001FBDC; // Random address :P
int value = *address; // Dereference of address
```

Meaning, is it possible to get the value of a particular address in memory ?

Thanks

Comment: Haven't you just tried it yet?

Comment: What do you want to do with the address if you can get it? Tip: Don't do it.

Comment: @Als - unavoidable sometimes, esp. in embedded or drivers.

Comment: @MartinJames: I will say If one needs to ask this question, then tip is still *Don't do it*.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can and should write it like this:

```
#include <cstdint>

uintptr_t p = 0x0001FBDC;
int value = *reinterpret_cast<int *>(p);
```

Note that unless there is some guarantee that `p` points to an integer, this is undefined behaviour. A standard operating system will kill your process if you try to access an address that it didn't expect you to address. However, this may be a common pattern in free-standing programs.

(Earlier versions of C++ should say `#include <stdint.h>` and `intptr_t`.)

Comment: In this case is there any difference between the c-style cast that OP uses and the `reinterpret_cast`? I think the latter just decays to the former in this case?

Comment: +1 for fixing the type mismatches, but yes, of course it will work, (with your caveat re. addressability, memory-management protections etc), else pointers would be unuseable!

Comment: @Als: Rather, the C-style cast decays to the `reinterpret_cast`. The meaning of C-style casts in C++ is defined in terms of the C++-style casts IIRC. As far as the compiler is concerned a C-style cast in C++ is normally just a way of saying, "um, I'm not sure what cast I want here, I'll take the chef's choice". I say normally because I think there are some dubious things you can do with a C-style cast but not with C++-style casts: casting bounder-to-derived to pointer-to-private-base or something.

Comment: @SteveJessop:True.Eitherway, the point is that both are same in this case or is there anything that I missed, which makes `reinterpret_cast` any better.

Comment: @Als: I don't believe you have missed anything.

Comment: Why `intptr_t` in earlier versions of C++?  `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` were added to the standards at the same time.  (On the other hand, since this sort of thing is obviously not portable, you might as well go ahead and use `unsigned`, if that's the correct size.  Or not... I like the documentation impact of `uintptr_t` anyway.)